# how to fit the content in all the screen resolution

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i'm new to css,
currently i'm working movie booking app.
here i want to fit the seat capacity inside of screen size but its going beyond the screen. i want to keep all the seats (rows and column) in side of the screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVSVL.png)

this is how its showing

i tried to increase the width but it isn't not working

```
.booking-row {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

here you can find the sample code  https://jsfiddle.net/8qya5ef3/1/

can anyone help me in this

Comment: For the record: your `.booking-row` with seats is not an `<img>` as you lead us to believe with posting the image, but a flexbox parent/child issue.  Please make sure to post a proper [reprex]. You now have answers discussing resizing an image instead of flexbox sizing.

Comment: How are you going to fit that many seats into a row on a portrait mode small smart phone or narrow viewport and still make it possible to view them or click on a specific one? Or are you going to rely on some sort of zoom capability?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.booking-row {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVSVL.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```